# Localization in email template sent by Kentico forms

Tags: kentico

I have developed a form using form builder in Kentico Xperience.
I am using localized strings for the titles and texts of my form components.

For example for a radio button component, I have
[image]

which consists of the following localized strings:

[image]

It works fine until the form is submitted and sent by email.
The email template is built as follow:

```
$$label:Participation$$:    $$value:Participation$$
```

But I receive email like:

```
Participation in meeting:   {$Form.Participation.Virtual$}
```

While I would like to receive the localized text in my email as follow:

```
Participation in meeting:   Virtually
```

How can I do that? Is there a specific syntax in the email template?

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax in my email template to obtain what I am looking for is:

```
$$label:Participation$$:    {%Participation%}
```

Comment: I would never have guessed `{%Participation%}` is evaluated as `$$value:Participation$$`. I wasted hours to find this. it's pretty useful for me to combine it with macros as well like `{% GetResourceString("key_prefix" + Participation ) %}`

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is by design. If you use a compoment with list of options and you add just a localization macro there, there is a risk that chaning the string will cause wrong values. The recommended and supported format is:

***value;{$ResourceStringKey$}***